# Highcharts - Linear series zoom on logarithmic axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having trouble when zooming in on a linear series that is on a logarithmic yAxis. What would be an easy solution?

Zoom out:
[image]

Zoom in:
[image]

Linear series is not rescaling correcly, those series should remain on same position relative to main series, is there any missing configs to those series that would adjust them to logarithmic axis?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/dfqouLm5/30/

Code snippet:

```js
Highcharts.stockChart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
    zoomType: "xy",
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [
        {
          x: -220924800000,
          high: 63,
          low: 56,
          close: 62,
          open: 56,
          name: "01/01/1963",
          color: "#F57350",
        },
        {
          x: 1657670400000,
          high: 18893.92,
          low: 18159.03,
          close: 18159.03,
          open: 18593.15,
          name: "13/07/2022",
          color: "#297F0D",
        },
      ],
      dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        groupPixelWidth: 0,
        units: [["day", 1]],
      },
      id: "main-series",
      name: "Demo series",
      type: "candlestick",
      yAxis: "default",
    },
    {
      color: "#C0C0C0",
      data: [
        [-220914000000, 369],
        [1659236400000, 198817.91340815497],
      ],
      dashStyle: "LongDash",
      id: "upper-tendency",
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 0,
        xDateFormat: "%B %Y",
      },
      showInLegend: false,
      yAxis: "default",
    },
    {
      color: "#C0C0C0",
      data: [
        [-220914000000, 34],
        [1659236400000, 16672.03531810569],
      ],
      dashStyle: "Solid",
      id: "lower-tendency",
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 0,
        xDateFormat: "%B %Y",
      },
      showInLegend: false,
      yAxis: "default",
    },
  ],
  title: { text: "Logarithmic Zoom: Linear series" },
  tooltip: { shared: true, split: false },
  xAxis: {
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      second: "%d/%m/%y<br/>%H:%M:%S",
      minute: "%d/%m/%y<br/>%H:%M",
      hour: "%d/%m/%y<br/>%H:%M",
      day: "%d/%m/%y",
      month: "%m/%y",
      year: "%Y",
    },
    type: "datetime",
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      id: "default",
      opposite: true,
      type: "logarithmic",
      title: { text: "" },
      reversed: false,
      offset: 50,
      tickInterval: 0.4,
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: I've just noticed that the problem is on `xAxis` zooming, if I set `chart : { zoomType: 'y' } ` series scales correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug which you can track in the following ticket:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16784

As a temporary workaround, you can set `xAxis.ordinal` to `false` in your config.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rfxygz5m/